# distribution for a subset of md5

Tags: hash, md5

I need to uniquely assign a 32 bit integer to a collection of human readable strings (i.e. they will not be generated with hash collision in mind).  I don't expect more than a few thousand strings.  I would like to evaluate the possibility of using the first 32 bits of the md5 sum for this.  What is the distribution of these bits?

Comment: I'll go a little off-topic, but... How about using this? https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/

Comment: Disclaimer: I have never used it, just saw it some weeks ago by coincidence in the MacPorts repository.

Comment: The collection can be extended, so unfortunately gperf will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is wanted to assign a 32-bit integer to *each* of human readable strings in some collection (for the problem as worded, the answer is [`00000000000000000000000000101010`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)).

Assuming that the human readable strings are chosen independently of the definition of MD5, then the first 32-bit of the MD5 hash of each string is about uniformly distributed. That would be a classical result for any hash that is a [PRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) (for any distinguisher able to recognize the first 32 bits from a random function can trivially be turned into a distinguisher for the full function). MD5 was designed with the goal to be a PRF, and remains good enough. Sorry I do not have a reference.

Odds that there is at least one collision with $n$ strings is
$$p=1-(2^{32})!/(2^{32}-n)!/2^{32\cdot n}\approx1-e^{-n\cdot(n-1)/2^{33}}\approx n\cdot(n-1)/2^{33}$$
The approximation on the right is quite good for $n$ up to about $2^{14}$, arguably including " *a few thousand strings* ". For $n=10,000$, $p\approx1.2\%$.

However, one knowing your plan to do this and in a position to generate the human readable strings can make the number of collisions high (including having all the strings giving `00000000000000000000000000101010`). That [MD5's collision resistance is now badly broken](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/170.pdf) is *not* relevant: the problem is that a 32-bit value is too small. To solve this issue (and return to the probability of collision previously stated even for evil choice of the strings), use a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) with a secret key, e.g. a truncated [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Note: the MAC solution also allows to solve the problem of finding a hash with no collision for a particular collection, known as a [perfect hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), in a simple way: try distinct keys at random until finding one for which there is no collision: that's easy to check with with $2^{32}$ bits (512 [MiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)) of RAM. It is tried on average $1/(1-p)$ keys and less than $n/(1-p)$ MAC computations. When $n$ grows past about $2^{17}$ that becomes increasingly impractical, and [dynamic perfect hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing) comes to the rescue.

Comment: The particular information I was seeking was "Assuming that the human readable strings are chosen independently of the definition of MD5, then the first 32-bit of the MD5 hash of each string is about uniformly distributed".  Where can I find a reference?

Comment: By human readable, I meant to convey 'not chosen with the intent of inducing collisions'

Comment: I am always a little taken aback by birthday problem calculations at an order of magnitude I hadn't seen before.  Intuition really fails, usually spectacularly.