# What is degree of randomness in individual bits of MD5 hash?

Tags: hash, reference-request, md5

I am researching on Hashing Algorithms and would like to know if we take individual bits of MD5, say we take first 8 bits or any random 8 bits of MD5 then what is the randomness probability of having same 8-bits (at exactly the same position) in any two different MD5 hashes ?

I´ve read somewhere that MD5 being good PRF has uniform randomness in each individual bit. Is this statement true? Also, is there any reference for this?

Comment: depends on the input. Is it allowed to be chosen by an attacker?

Comment: Lets say attacker can choose the input but what if we add 128-bit random text to the input before MD5 hash is done. (which means even if attacker chooses the input the input to MD5 will be different in each case) How does that affect the randomness of each bit of MD5 ?

Comment: Please tell me you are not using MD5 in a real system.

Comment: No its just a research interest.

Comment: So if an attacker sends you $A$ and $B$, you'll return him $H(A||R_1)$ and $H(B||R_2)$ with the R's being random strings? I think one can apply MD5 collision attacks against this... (not 100% sure though...)

Comment: The only problems we have with MD5 is that one can "easily" construct collisions against it. Everything else should be fine with MD5, especially (2nd) preimage resistance isn't broken (yet).

Comment: @SEJPM Sorry for not being clear, If the system adds two different random strings to passed input e.g. **H(A||R1)** & **H(B||R2)**. Attacker has no control over to these R1 and R2 and are chosen randomly.

Comment: Sorry I think I was wrong. The collision attack shouldn't apply. Oh and if you look for "mathy" formatting, try putting `$H(A||R_1), H(B||R_2)$`.

Comment: [What @mikeazo said…](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26850/what-is-degree-of-randomness-in-individual-bits-of-md5-hash#comment62490_26850)$^{+1}$ because it´s well known that [MD5  is a dead fish in cryptographical waters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MD5 was designed with the goal that any change in the input uniformly affects all the bits of the output. It's not perfect, but it's pretty good. If you're choosing the input "randomly enough" (e.g., by appending random bits before hashing) then your question approaches this one:

> Given two randomly generated 8-bit strings, what is the probability
>   that they match?

This is $\frac{1}{2^{8}}$.

References:

- [RFC 1321](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt), Rivest's original description of the MD5 algorithm
- [How to Break MD5 and Other Hash Functions](http://merlot.usc.edu/csac-f06/papers/Wang05a.pdf), by Wang and Yu
- [The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819712/is-any-substring-of-an-encrypted-hash-md5-sha1-more-random-than-another)
- [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860405/are-the-first-32-bits-of-an-md5-hash-just-as-random-as-any-other-substring?rq=1)
- [Slightly differently](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/distribution-for-a-subset-of-md5)
- [Yet again](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/517/does-md5-generate-128-independent-bits)
- [And again](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/distribution-for-a-subset-of-md5)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link. I have a query that should we consider bit difference you have mentioned is based upon the binary data right ? Like either it can be 0 or 1 and hence for 8 bits it can be 1/2^8

Comment: Yes, that's right - a [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) is binary by definition. MD5 takes an input of arbitrary length - any number of bits - and produces 128 bits of output. Typically this output is displayed as a string of 32 hex digits.

Comment: MD5 output is uniformly random in each case of MD5 ? I mean for any random input given to the MD5, the hash generated is uniformly random ? (the probability of output collision is equal in each case) 
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Given random inputs, the output of MD5 is statistically uniformly random. MD5 is "broken" not because the distribution of its outputs is skewed, but because careful cryptanalysis showed that it's possible to create inputs that yield specific outputs. However, these "special" inputs are few and far between when compared to the space of all possible inputs, so they don't really affect the statistical properties of MD5's output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any reference which says MD5 output is uniformly random ?

Comment: Yes... there's a whole list of them above. Uniformity over the set of possible outputs is a [characteristic of hash functions in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity). If that's not convincing enough, then you can always write a script that hashes a bunch of random data and check for yourself.

Comment: Does MD5 follow the rule of uniformity ?